# High Active(file) Memory Usage in Oracle Linux VMs

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, memory, linux-kernel, hadoop

I recently searched and read lots of posts and questions about Linux memory management but I can't find my case. For example, there is a question in Unix StackExchange about [High memory usage but no process is using it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259659/high-memory-usage-but-no-process-is-using-it). In this post, the accepted answer describes virtual memory ballooning. In my case, no ballooning exist. The output of `vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon` in all nodes is `0 MB`

I have a simple Hadoop cluster with CDH on three virtualized Oracle Linux VMs. All things configured Correctly. All Cloudera installation tests passed and no warning on Cloudera manager.

On a fresh reboot condition, All things are good. after reboot, all nodes memory usage is reasonable. I start MySQL database service for Cloudera manager and other CDH services. also, I start all installed CDH services in these three nodes. after a while, I see some unreasonable memory usage in all the nodes. It takes near one month to get this condition but I think something is wrong.

I stopped all the services in all nodes including installed CDH services, Cloudera manager services, and MySQL database. I see only some Oracle Linux native process like gnome-shell in the top, but there is a High Active(file) memory usage in /proc/meminfo. Notice no active process use it. In the following, I write the output of some Linux commands on all three nodes.

***First node with 72 GByte memory:***

`# top`

```
top - 10:07:29 up 43 days, 22:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 335 total,   1 running, 334 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 73964544 total, 62105912 free, 10447080 used,  1411556 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 31457276 total, 31457276 free,        0 used. 72295264 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 9284 gdm       20   0 4493724 168588  80536 S   0.0  0.2   1:09.89 gnome-shell
  657 root      20   0  211512 139828 139328 S   0.0  0.2   2:02.12 systemd-journal
 1321 root      20   0  417540 114112 112620 S   0.0  0.2   3:38.10 rsyslogd
 9184 root      20   0  417184  30108  21796 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.46 X
 1808 root      20   0  687472  25908  12760 S   0.0  0.0  23:24.98 python2.7
 9404 gdm       20   0 1091248  24988  19520 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.60 gsd-media-keys
 9406 gdm       20   0  651064  23064  17928 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.82 gsd-power
 9387 gdm       20   0  634648  22980  17756 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.20 gsd-xsettings
 9396 gdm       20   0  657552  22976  17972 S   0.0  0.0   0:27.73 gsd-color
 9361 gdm       20   0  484424  22492  17656 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.15 ibus-x11
 9385 gdm       20   0  566536  22368  17348 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.19 gsd-wacom
 9389 gdm       20   0  570760  22276  17360 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 gsd-a11y-keyboa
 9402 gdm       20   0  642340  22220  17376 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 gsd-keyboard
 9393 gdm       20   0  484044  21852  17016 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 gsd-clipboard
 1059 polkitd   20   0  546320  19184   9708 S   0.0  0.0  10:11.73 polkitd
 1883 root      20   0  224860  18236   3772 S   0.0  0.0 105:21.35 python
 1982 root      20   0  212752  15816   7396 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 python2.7
 9419 gdm       20   0  721080  15256  13260 S   0.0  0.0   0:59.14 gsd-smartcard
 9214 gdm       20   0  696804  14056  11804 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.96 gnome-session-b
 1045 root      20   0  480552  14044  11728 S   0.0  0.0   0:29.82 NetworkManager
 9421 gdm       20   0  577744  13312  11448 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 gsd-sound
 9397 gdm       20   0  495504  13056  11212 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 gsd-datetime
 9407 gdm       20   0  484744  12320  10572 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 gsd-print-notif
```

`# ps aux | awk '{sum+=$6} END {print sum / 1024}'`

```
1163.8
```

`# free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          72231       10201       60650         550        1378       70601
Swap:         30719           0       30719
```

`# cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:       73964548 kB
MemFree:        62105864 kB
MemAvailable:   72295336 kB
Buffers:            1036 kB
Cached:           758788 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          7807136 kB
Inactive:        2962332 kB
Active(anon):     281104 kB
Inactive(anon):   547168 kB
Active(file):    7526032 kB
Inactive(file):  2415164 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      31457276 kB
SwapFree:       31457276 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        264356 kB
Mapped:           208956 kB
Shmem:            563972 kB
Slab:             651816 kB
SReclaimable:     573188 kB
SUnreclaim:        78628 kB
KernelStack:        8592 kB
PageTables:        22452 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    68439548 kB
Committed_AS:    2689848 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      370120 kB
VmallocChunk:   34321002492 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      210880 kB
DirectMap2M:    19712000 kB
DirectMap1G:    57671680 kB
```

***Second node with 36 GByte memory:***

`# top`

```
top - 10:07:58 up 43 days, 22:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 336 total,   1 running, 335 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 36807704 total, 29874328 free,  5905568 used,  1027808 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 31457276 total, 31457276 free,        0 used. 35350592 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1865 gdm       20   0 4561224 251136  82240 S   0.0  0.7  29:28.13 gnome-shell
  649 root      20   0  211356 138832 138340 S   0.0  0.4   2:03.48 systemd-journal
 1341 root      20   0  417384 112980 111484 S   0.0  0.3   3:18.25 rsyslogd
 2229 gdm       20   0  735040  33768  17968 S   0.0  0.1 103:09.50 gsd-color
 1683 root      20   0  417204  30532  22216 S   0.0  0.1   0:23.65 X
29070 root      20   0  687476  25824  12676 S   0.0  0.1  10:43.35 python2.7
 2241 gdm       20   0 1017516  24812  19372 S   0.0  0.1   0:10.19 gsd-media-keys
 2243 gdm       20   0  651068  23196  18064 S   0.0  0.1   0:15.36 gsd-power
 2219 gdm       20   0  634644  22872  17668 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.22 gsd-xsettings
 2152 gdm       20   0  484424  22360  17536 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 ibus-x11
 2215 gdm       20   0  566536  22240  17236 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.18 gsd-wacom
 2240 gdm       20   0  642336  22164  17348 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.18 gsd-keyboard
 2222 gdm       20   0  570756  21880  16976 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.17 gsd-a11y-keyboa
 2225 gdm       20   0  484044  21668  16852 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.16 gsd-clipboard
 1093 polkitd   20   0  546320  19000   9556 S   0.0  0.1  10:19.18 polkitd
 1717 root      20   0  223220  16620   3812 S   0.0  0.0  44:34.87 python
 1731 root      20   0  212752  15832   7416 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.71 python2.7
 2257 gdm       20   0  721208  15032  13040 S   0.0  0.0  25:09.76 gsd-smartcard
 1750 gdm       20   0  696800  13964  11712 S   0.0  0.0   0:34.28 gnome-session-b
 1071 root      20   0  480520  13844  11500 S   0.0  0.0   0:31.47 NetworkManager
 2258 gdm       20   0  577744  13148  11276 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 gsd-sound
 2235 gdm       20   0  495504  12872  11028 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 gsd-datetime
 2245 gdm       20   0  484744  12176  10424 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 gsd-print-notif
```

`# ps aux | awk '{sum+=$6} END {print sum / 1024}'`

```
1247.77
```

`# free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          35945        5765       29175         511        1003       34523
Swap:         30719           0       30719
```

`# cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:       36807704 kB
MemFree:        29875428 kB
MemAvailable:   35351836 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:           691300 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          5482728 kB
Inactive:         785216 kB
Active(anon):     369828 kB
Inactive(anon):   506792 kB
Active(file):    5112900 kB
Inactive(file):   278424 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      31457276 kB
SwapFree:       31457276 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        353336 kB
Mapped:           210668 kB
Shmem:            523288 kB
Slab:             336724 kB
SReclaimable:     268132 kB
SUnreclaim:        68592 kB
KernelStack:        8592 kB
PageTables:        22688 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    49861128 kB
Committed_AS:    2750840 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      268540 kB
VmallocChunk:   34340171772 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      180160 kB
DirectMap2M:     9256960 kB
DirectMap1G:    30408704 kB
```

***Third node with 24 GByte memory:***

`# top`

```
top - 10:08:01 up 43 days, 22:11,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 335 total,   1 running, 334 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 24422436 total, 17590640 free,  5837736 used,   994060 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 31457276 total, 31457276 free,        0 used. 23084448 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1820 gdm       20   0 4556244 244876  82152 S   0.0  1.0  28:58.89 gnome-shell
  647 root      20   0  211328 139016 138516 S   0.0  0.6   2:01.63 systemd-journal
 1330 root      20   0  417356 112584 111100 S   0.0  0.5   2:56.85 rsyslogd
 2084 gdm       20   0  661304  33656  17880 S   0.0  0.1  90:41.83 gsd-color
 1669 root      20   0  417184  30612  22296 S   0.0  0.1   0:23.21 X
 1838 root      20   0  687472  25684  12540 S   0.0  0.1  22:38.69 python2.7
 2094 gdm       20   0 1230516  24960  19484 S   0.0  0.1   0:10.22 gsd-media-keys
 2098 gdm       20   0  651064  23148  18020 S   0.0  0.1   0:15.32 gsd-power
 2076 gdm       20   0  634648  23000  17804 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 gsd-xsettings
 2074 gdm       20   0  566536  22348  17348 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.21 gsd-wacom
 2079 gdm       20   0  570756  22080  17180 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.16 gsd-a11y-keyboa
 2035 gdm       20   0  484424  22024  17204 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.14 ibus-x11
 2093 gdm       20   0  642336  21904  17088 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.17 gsd-keyboard
 2083 gdm       20   0  484044  21816  16996 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.18 gsd-clipboard
 1071 polkitd   20   0  546312  18812   9372 S   0.0  0.1  10:10.08 polkitd
 1719 root      20   0  222800  16056   3708 S   0.0  0.1  31:42.76 python
 1724 root      20   0  212752  15692   7276 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.62 python2.7
 2111 gdm       20   0  721080  15116  13120 S   0.0  0.1  23:53.20 gsd-smartcard
 1714 gdm       20   0  696800  13876  11620 S   0.0  0.1   0:34.06 gnome-session-b
 1049 root      20   0  480512  13872  11580 S   0.0  0.1   0:30.41 NetworkManager
 2115 gdm       20   0  577744  12984  11116 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 gsd-sound
 2085 gdm       20   0  495504  12848  11004 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 gsd-datetime
 2099 gdm       20   0  484744  12052  10304 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 gsd-print-notif
```

`# ps aux | awk '{sum+=$6} END {print sum / 1024}'`

```
1240.27
```

`# free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          23850        5701       17177         507         970       22542
Swap:         30719           0       30719
```

`# cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:       24422436 kB
MemFree:        17590524 kB
MemAvailable:   23084532 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:           687492 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          5470816 kB
Inactive:         780568 kB
Active(anon):     361540 kB
Inactive(anon):   504624 kB
Active(file):    5109276 kB
Inactive(file):   275944 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      31457276 kB
SwapFree:       31457276 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        346348 kB
Mapped:           210440 kB
Shmem:            519888 kB
Slab:             306796 kB
SReclaimable:     241160 kB
SUnreclaim:        65636 kB
KernelStack:        8592 kB
PageTables:        22624 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    43668492 kB
Committed_AS:    2753904 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      215184 kB
VmallocChunk:   34346561532 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      180160 kB
DirectMap2M:     7159808 kB
DirectMap1G:    19922944 kB
```

As you can see Active(file) is the main memory usage field. I read about Active(file) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487506/what-is-inactivefile-and-activefile-in-proc-meminfo). As mentioned in the answer, active is the total amount of buffer or page cache memory, in kilobytes, that is in active use. This is the memory that has been recently used and is usually not reclaimed for other purposes.

As I said all services are down. I want to release this memory. while the cluster is running, this memory increase day by day. All nodes are virtualized Oracle Linux 7.5 on VMware ESXi.

I will appreciate someone gives me some point to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ has good advice: Don't Panic!
Your RAM is fine!

Notice that `MemAvailable` is about 95% of `MemTotal`, or to put another way only 5% allocated for non-cache use. Plenty of memory on those boxes, at least in this idle state.

File caches are available memory, easily used for other purposes. Do not worry about the label of `Active(file)`, that's only relative to other caches. Anonymous, shared and other non file backed pages have a higher priority than caches.

File caches remain around after user processes are gone because they are a function of the file system in the kernel. Keeping these improves performance for all processes reading those files. Otherwise this memory would be wasted. Manually dropping is only useful for benchmarks from cold caches, there is no reason to do so in operational procedures.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are right. I wrote a simple python code to use all the memory. after that, Active(file) memory drastically reduced.

Answer (score 0):

The increase you talk about does not seem abnormal. You have 61/72, 29/36 and 17/24 free GB of RAM. It is normal for usage to increase overtime in many cases for such nodes.

Many things that use databases can preallocate a defined amount of memory. For example, I run some SAP servers which always will have 40GB out of 48GB full, due to the 40GB being preallocated for SQL. If you check the server's memory status, nothing is relevant there since the 40GB will always show as full. There are no issues here; the rest of 8GB is more than enough for the system to run and the 40GB for SQL can handle all workloads the SAP throws at it. This prevents any problems with server running out of memory. But, in such a case, you'll have to check how much of the preallocated RAM is in use in SQL, instead of checking the OS RAM status. Maybe such a tactic could be more helpful in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I stop the database service and no daemon exists for it. this amount of ram is not preallocated and increase over time. in a long-running cluster situation, I see all memory filled. I think there is a problem with 61/72, 29/36 and 17/24 free GB of RAM with no process running.

Comment: If you can stop the service at will, try after that to clear systemcache, proccache and sessioncache. Note that this does not release the occupied memory, it just clears the caches. Also, some mysql info about memory may help make further determinations: select event_name, current_alloc, high_alloc from sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes where  current_count > 0; (you may have to enable mem metrics collection 1st, if not active already: UPDATE setup_instruments SET ENABLED = 'YES'
WHERE NAME LIKE 'memory/%';)

Comment: I strongly believe that MySQL is not the source of the problem. I have MySQL in the first node with 72 GB of memory but I see the problem in all three nodes. I cleared PageCache, dentries, and inodes with `# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ` command.

Comment: No, MySQL is not the problem, it just adapts to the data received, but its behavior can be optimized/customized.